# Посылать к черту

Tags: этимология

Посылать к черту, как появился этот брань на Руси?
Хотел бы узнать этимологию, историю если есть...

Answer (score 3):

А что вас удивляет в этой фразе? Пожелание отправляться к нечистой силе, гораздо логичнее, чем более распространённый матерный посыл. Аналоги подобного выражения существуют  почти во всех языках мира. Пожелание появилось явно очень давно, но когда конкретно сказать невозможно, из-за разговорного характера данной фразы.

Comment: Я не говорил, на сколько удивительно и неожиданно посылать к черту, а этимологией интересовался.

Comment: Выражение по всем признаком появилось раньше чем письменность у славян, соответственно сказать когда именно начали испльзовать выражение невозможно.

Слово "чёрт", по Фасмеру, от праслав. *čьrtъ рассматривается как прич. на -tо- "проклятый". "Слать" тоже общеславянское слово от праслав.  *sъlati

Answer (score 1):

Пожелание охотнику «ни пуха, ни пера!» изначально употреблялось как заклинание, чтобы обмануть нечистую силу. Ответ «к чёрту» – это предложение попросить чёрта, чтобы охотнику не досталось ни пуха, ни пера. Считалось, что чёрт, по своему обыкновению, сделает наоборот, и охотник вернётся с богатой добычей..

Answer (score 0):

Чёрт . Язычество . Знаем, проходили . Истукан в капище . У христиан икона в храме . Смысл один - подмога верующему .

Comment: А вот и соврал. Чёрт скорее ИДОЛ . Истукан немного другое .Идол- подделка , фальшивка .Ай, нехорошо получилось . Так ведь говорят и Дьявол был когда -то , лучшим учеником Бога.Здесь видимо произошло хроно- наслоение . Когда персонаж меняет своё амплуа .